# Jenkins Multibranch Builds

Tags: c#, jenkins

In my company we have a C# repo that had to be structured a little differently. We have multiple Projects in the same Solution that all have their own `Jenkinsfile`. When a PR is created for one of projects it builds every project, even if there was no changes made inside that project.

In Jenkins we have a `Build included regions strategy` with a setup like this `**/ProjectName/**`

This was the only way that we had found to get anything to build properly.

We have tried different structures to the `Build included regions strategy` such as `**/ProjectName`, `ProjectName/**`, `*/ProjectName/*`, `*ProjectName`, `ProjectName/*`. I also tried to add a `Cancel build excluded region strategy` with a setup like

```
**/Project1/**
**/Project2/**
**/Project3/**
**/Project4/**
**/Project5/**
```

We need it only build the Project that is being effected with the PR. It only does it when a PR is created. If there is just a commit done on a branch or the PR, it just builds that project. Our Jenkins Pipeline is the same for both actions.